# Legend for points

Tags: ilnumerics

I add multiple 3d points sets to a plot cube as follows:

```
points 
|> List.map (fun (z, size, color, label) ->
    let points = new ILPoints(label)
    points.Positions <- positionBuffer z
    points.Size <- float32 size
    points.Color <- new System.Nullable<Color>(color)
    points)
|> List.iter (fun points -> plotcube.Add points)
```

This works fine, I can assign color and size as I like. Now I would like to display
a legend entry for each of the set of points. However, when I just do it the simple way

```
let legend = 
   new ILLegend(points |> List.map (fun (z, size, color, label) -> label) |> List.toArray)
plotcube.Add(legend)
```

I get an empty legend. How can I get it to work? Is it possible to add a legend for points in a 3d plot at all?

Many thanks for any tips or ideas

Comment: What is the legend supposed to display for each ILPoints shape? Only color and size? (Expecting here, the point shapes use single color rendering as in your example)

Comment: I would be very happy with a color and of course the label. I give a label to the points in the constructor. So in principle the data should be there. I read about custom legends but did not get any further.

Answer (score 1):

Legends show information for objects which support the `IILLegendDataProvider` interface. `ILPoints` do not. Currently two objects exist, which are suitable to be used in conjunctino with ILLegend: `ILLinePlot` and `ILContourPlot`. You have several options:

1. Use `ILLinePlot` instead. You could hide the line and only use markers on the line plot. This will immediately enable the legend also. This solution is only feasable, if the number of points is reasonable low, since markers are expensive to draw.
2. Create a custom class derived from `ILPoints` or `ILGroup`. Implement the `IILLegendDataProvider` interface on it. Add the legend as sibling to your class. This will work for ILNumerics Ultimate VS only, since in the Community Edition there is no option of creating custom scene graph objects.